# Linux shell script how can I create an Oracle table only if table does not exist

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, unix, sh

I am new to Linux, I want to check if a table does not exist in Oracle than create a new table using Linux shell script to write the code. I probably need to do an if else statement?

Here is my code for creating table in Oracle

```
Create table traffic_profile_external
(
  TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID    NUMBER,     
  PE_INGRESS_FLAG       VARCHAR2(1),
  PE_EGRESS_FLAG        VARCHAR2(1),
  CE_INGRESS_FLAG       VARCHAR2(1),
  CE_EGRESS_FLAG        VARCHAR2(1),
  COS_PROFILE_TYPE      VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see whether a table exists by querying `dba_|all_|user_tables` depending on your privileges, whether you're potentially creating tables in other schemas, etc.  So you can do something like

```
select count(*)
  from all_tables
 where owner = <<schema that owns the table>>
   and table_name = 'TRAFFIC_PROFILE_EXTERNAL'
```

and then based on the result that is returned decide whether to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You can do that in an anonymous PL/SQL block but then you'd have to use dynamic SQL (via the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement) in order to run the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You could also fetch the result of the `SELECT` statement into a variable in your shell script and branch based on that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS traffic_profile_external
(
   TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID    NUMBER,     
   PE_INGRESS_FLAG       VARCHAR2(1),
   PE_EGRESS_FLAG        VARCHAR2(1),
   CE_INGRESS_FLAG       VARCHAR2(1),
   CE_EGRESS_FLAG        VARCHAR2(1),
   COS_PROFILE_TYPE      VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Comment: `create table if not exists` isn't valid syntax in Oracle.

Comment: I got the information from here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html

Comment: That's a MySQL manual.  That's another product that is owned by Oracle the corporation.  Oracle Corp owns a number of different relational database products including MySQL and Oracle.  MySQL and Oracle support very different dialects of SQL.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.